Is DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP worthless if you already run DBCC CHECKDB on all databases?
DBCC CHECKDB makes many other integrity checks redundant, but I can't see anything in the documentation saying if it makes DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP redundant. Is DBCC CHECKFILEGROUP worthless if you already run DBCC CHECKDB on all databases?

There should be no need to run CHECKFILEGROUP if you've already run CHECKDB. The checks are redundant as checkdb will already check allocations, system metadata, and run CHECKTABLE on all tables and views.
